# Browserify can't find module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to include a react component to my rails app.  React is working but Browserify cant find the component.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-typeahead' from '/Users/xxx/code/xxx/app/assets/javascripts/react'
```

I used bower to add react-typeahead to `vendor/assets/components` and I'm trying to include it with: `config.browserify_rails.paths << /vendor\/assets\/\/components\/\/react-typeahead\//`

How can I get Browserify to load the component?

Comment: I would try https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails or seperate out your frontend code into a seperate project managed by npm. See http://harrymoreno.com/2015/06/10/React-on-Rails.html